# Remote debugging ASP.NET Web Service in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, remote-debugging

I've set up the Remote Debugging service, made sure all necessary permissions are set (as far as I can tell). The remote debugging monitor even sees me connecting. But I can't hit any breakpoints in my deployed service!

The server is a VM on the same domain. The project is an ASP.NET Web Service project built with debug=true in the web.config.

What am I doing wrong? When I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio it just gets marked as "This breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols..."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the web service project is being built in Debug mode.